# Numpy delivering different result

Tags: python, numpy

can someone explain why these 2 operations deliver different results? has it to do with some sort of maximum output?
I don't mean the difference in time, but in the calculated result.

```
l = list(range(100000000))
a = np.arange(100000000)

%time np.sum(a ** 2)
CPU times: user 132 ms, sys: 217 ms, total: 348 ms
Wall time: 347 ms
662921401752298880

%time sum([x ** 2 for x in l])
CPU times: user 23.8 s, sys: 1.32 s, total: 25.1 s
Wall time: 25.1 s
333333328333333350000000
```

Comment: Numpy uses Int64, which overflow over a certain limit. Python ints automatically switch to big integers that do not overflow. Python list comprehension has the right result.

Comment: Then maybe you could try dtype='object' for the np.array. (could not try myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [pLOPeGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8118087/plopegg), [BLimitless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14154784/blimitless) and [KaPy3141](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10900526/kapy3141) `numpy`'s integers can overflow. You can circumvent that by specifying `dtype='object'` (with minor speedup):

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: n = 10_000_000

In [3]: %timeit np.sum(np.arange(n, dtype='object')**2)
2.28 s ± 56.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit sum(i**2 for i in range(n))
2.6 s ± 534 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# also just for completeness sake
# multiplying with itself is considerably faster than squaring explicitly
In [5]: %timeit sum(i*i for i in range(n))
1.29 s ± 242 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# fastest thing I could come up with:
In [6]: %timeit a = np.arange(n, dtype='object'); np.sum(a * a)
939 ms ± 74.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your explanations, just tried it myself. Do you know why the python list calculation is even even faster than the numpy calculation ?

Comment: It's not though - versions using `numpy` still outperform

Comment: Usually object dtype math times about the same as lists. Both use the same sort of object referencing, not the faster compiled `c` methods used for numeric dtypes.

Comment: Generally accessing the object protocol through numpy slows things down. When you find yourself using `dtype=object` it's generally a safe bet to switch to using a list or so

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. For me list calculation was even aster than numpy that's why I was curious. hpaulj and Mad Pysicist's answers make sense to me =)

Answer (score 1):

@robin has it right: numpy is overflowing the int size. This is a known issue and will hopefully be fixed soon. These links have more info:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10964